# How to query if just one record of a grouped result set satisfies a condition?

Tags: sql, group-by

I've created [this db fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cyqwoMx2Dy5D3BVCRHoRb5/0) to help illustrate the issue. Basically I want the last four records that were inserted into the table to be excluded from the result set. The reason they should be excluded and the first four records should be included is because I'm looking for just the records from the same person which have the same amount and at least one of those records has the description of 'fee'. However I'm not sure how to check for the last part of that sentence. Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to check the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do, feel free to ask any concern,

```
Select * 
from tableA C
where exists(
Select * From 
tableA a JOIN
tableA b on a.PersonId=b.PersonId and a.Amount=b.Amount and a.Description ='fee' and 
b.Description!='fee'
where C.PersonId=a.PersonId and C.Amount=a.Amount)
```